# python finding and replacing list item if substring exist

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, substring

I want to replace the item in a list that contains a certain substring. In this case the item the contains "NSW" (capitals are important) in any form should be replaced by "NSW = 0". It doesn´t matter if the original entry reads "NSW = 500" or "NSW = 501". I can find the list item but somehow i can not find the postion in the list so i could replace it? This is what i came up with, but i replaces all items:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, with_statement
my_list =["abc 123","acd 234","NSW = 500", "stuff","morestuff"]
for index, i in enumerate(my_list):
    if any("NSW" in s for s in my_list):
        print ("found")
        my_list[index]= "NSW = 0"
print (my_list)
```

Comment: If you are performing replacement by index, there's really no need for `any`.

Comment: Get rid of the `any`. Instead, use `if "NSW" in i:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any` won't give you the index and it will always be true at each iteration. So drop it...

Personally I'd use a list comprehension with a ternary to decide to keep the original data or replace by `NSW = 0`:

```
my_list =["abc 123","acd 234","NSW = 500", "stuff","morestuff"]

result = ["NSW = 0" if "NSW" in x else x for x in my_list]
```

result:

```
['abc 123', 'acd 234', 'NSW = 0', 'stuff', 'morestuff']
```

Comment: I am sorry, i really didn´t find the linked thread

Answer (score 3):

Simple `list comprehension`:

```
>>> ["NSW = 0" if "NSW" in ele else ele for ele in l]
```

#driver values :

```
IN :    l = ["abc 123", "acd 234", "NSW = 500", "stuff", "morestuff"]
OUT : ['abc 123', 'acd 234', 'NSW = 0', 'stuff', 'morestuff']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:
**code:**

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, with_statement
my_list =["abc 123","acd 234","NSW = 500", "stuff","morestuff"]
for index in xrange(len(my_list)):
    if "NSW" in my_list[index]:
        my_list[index] = "NSW = 0"

print (my_list)
```

**output:**

```
['abc 123', 'acd 234', 'NSW = 0', 'stuff', 'morestuff']
```

or you can use list comprehension for purpose as follows:

**code:**

```
my_list =["abc 123","acd 234","NSW = 500", "stuff","morestuff"]

print ["NSW = 0" if "NSW" in _ else _ for _ in my_list]
```

**output:**

```
['abc 123', 'acd 234', 'NSW = 0', 'stuff', 'morestuff']
```